# How to make style of SubmitButton consistent with Button style in Google App Script UI?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am building an UI form via code (not using the UI Builder) and I noticed that the SubmitButton class style is not consistent with the Button class look & feel.
Would you know any way to adjust the look & feel of either the Button class or the SubmitButton class to make them similar.

I noticed that the Button has a call setStylePrimaryName, setStyleName etc... but the documentation is vague - says: "This is useful for debugging"!!!

Any suggestion?

See below screenshoot, first button is of class Button, second button is SubmitButton. You can see they don't even align.

[image: Screen Shoot]

Comment: could you show a screen capture of both elements ? and tell which one you prefer ?

Comment: Hi Serge, I prefer the SubmitButton style; but most of my Forms are using the class Button. So I would like to know how to style everything as a Button class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style (a button) the way you want with `setStyleAttribute`

```
var _btn= {
    "background-color":"none",
    "background":"none",
    "width":"80px",
    "height":"24px",
    "border":"None",
    "font-family":"hobo std",
    "font-size":"0.9em",
    "color":"3f3f3f",
    "opacity":"1",
}
....
....
  var closeb = app.createButton("Submit");
  library.applyCSS(submit,_btn);
....
....
```

And in your library you have the function (credits to [James Fereira](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/gs-interactive))

```
function applyCSS(element, style){
  for (var key in style){
    element.setStyleAttribute(key, style[key]); 
  }  
}
```

Comment: `submit.setStyleAttributes(_btn)` - will do the same thing as that custom applyCSS()

Comment: Thanks Jacob, Bryan. Works fine to set the main Button style. But do you know how I would associate the **:hover**, **:active** and **[disabled]** CSS style to the same button?

Comment: in the documentation of the [button class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_button) and the [Submit button class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_submitbutton) you can read about the atributes `setEnabled()` and `addMouseOverHandler`

Comment: I see, I added the `addMouseOverHandler` handler to `setStyleAttribute` on the Button for the mouse over and a `addMouseOutHandler` to remove the style. Not practical, I hope Google will fix the styles of SubmitButton & Button to match. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this cosmetic dilemma by using multiple submit buttons in the same form. I experimented with CSS sans success; the Submit & Reset buttons are two unique beasts in the world of button widgets.
 [Here is some working code](http://pastebin.com/pX5P1NcA) 
that demonstrates a multiple page form where each page uses three `submitButton's` to advance back and forth doing multiple `doPost()'s`.

```
// Muliple page form using Google Apps Script

function doGet(eventInfo)  {return GUI(eventInfo)};
function doPost(eventInfo) {return GUI(eventInfo)};

function GUI (eventInfo) {
  var n = (eventInfo.parameter.state == void(0) ? 0 : parseInt(eventInfo.parameter.state));
  var ui = ((n == 0)? UiApp.createApplication() : UiApp.getActiveApplication());
  var Form;
  switch(n){
    case 0: {
      Form = getForm(eventInfo,n); // Use identical forms for demo purpose only
    } break;
    case 1: {
      Form = getForm(eventInfo,n); // In reality, each form would differ but...
    } break;
    default: {
      Form = getForm(eventInfo,n) // each form must abide by (implement) the hidden state variable
    } break;
  }
  return ui.add(Form);
};

function getForm(eventInfo,n) {
  var ui = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  // Increment the ID stored in a hidden text-box
  var state = ui.createTextBox().setId('state').setName('state').setValue(1+n).setVisible(true).setEnabled(false);
  var H1 = ui.createHTML("<H1>Form "+n+"</H1>");
  var H2 = ui.createHTML(
    "<h2>"+(eventInfo.parameter.formId==void(0)?"":"Created by submission of form "+eventInfo.parameter.formId)+"</h2>");

  // Add three submit buttons to go forward, backward and to validate the form
  var Next = ui.createSubmitButton("Next").setEnabled(true).setVisible(true);
  var Back = ui.createSubmitButton("Back").setEnabled(n>1).setVisible(true);
  var Validate = ui.createSubmitButton("Validate").setEnabled(n>0).setVisible(true);
  var Buttons = ui.createHorizontalPanel().add(Back).add(Validate).add(Next);
  var Body = ui.createVerticalPanel().add(H1).add(H2).add(state).add(Buttons).add(getParameters(eventInfo));
  var Form = ui.createFormPanel().setId((n>0?'doPost[':'doGet[')+n+']').add(Body);

  // Add client handlers using setText() to adjust state prior to form submission
  // NB: Use of the .setValue(val) and .setValue(val,bool) methods give runtime errors!
  var onClickValidateHandler = ui.createClientHandler().forTargets(state).setText(''+(parseInt(n)));
  var onClickBackHandler = ui.createClientHandler().forTargets(state).setText(''+(parseInt(n)-1));
  Validate.addClickHandler(onClickValidateHandler);
  Back.addClickHandler(onClickBackHandler);

  // Add a client handler executed prior to form submission
  var onFormSubmit = ui.createClientHandler()
  .forTargets(state).setEnabled(true) // Enable so value gets included in post parameters
  .forTargets(Body).setStyleAttribute("backgroundColor","#EEE");    
  Form.addSubmitHandler(onFormSubmit);

  return Form;
}

function getParameters(eventInfo) {
  var ui = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var panel = ui.createVerticalPanel().add(ui.createLabel("Parameters: "));
  for( p in eventInfo.parameter)
    panel.add(ui.createLabel(" - " + p + " = " + eventInfo.parameter[p]));
  return panel;
}
```

The code uses a single "hidden" state (here visualized in a `TextBox`) and multiple `SubmitButton`'s to allow the user to advance forward and backward through the form sequence, as well as to validate the contents of the form.  The two extra `SubmitButton`'s are "rewired" using `ClientHandler`'s that simply modify the hidden state prior to form submission.

**Notes**

- Note the use of the `.setText(value)` method in the client handler's.  Using the Chrome browser I get weird runtime errors if I switch to either of the `TextBox`'s `.setValue(value)` or `.setValue(value, fireEvents)` methods.
- I tried (unsuccessfully) to implement this logic using a `Script Property` instead of the hidden TextBox.  Instead of client handlers, this requires using server handlers. The behavior is erratic, suggesting to me that the asynchronous server-side events are occurring after the form submission event.